# Saw the Big Hand and believed in Moshe

Tags: beshalach, moshe-rabbeinu

וַיַּרְא יִשְׂרָאֵל אֶת הַיָּד הַגְּדֹלָה אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה יְ־הֹוָ־ה בְּמִצְרַיִם וַיִּירְאוּ הָעָם אֶת יְ־הֹוָ־ה וַיַּאֲמִינוּ בַּי־הֹוָ־ה וּבְמֹשֶׁה עַבְדּוֹ:

What Big Hand are we talking about and why did this HAND cause a belief in Moshe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer is said that the big hand is Basyaha's hand which grew when she stretched out to reach for Moshe.

Comment: Do you have a source for this explanation? Why would the Jews now believe in Moshe because of a story that happened 80 years before?

Comment: what story? Some miracle happen 80 years ago?